# Xamarin Forms Android Memory Issues When Loading Images

Tags: android, image, memory, xamarin

So I have this app in Xamarin.Droid that basically loads an image that loads from resource that's only 168KB. Before loading the image, the app's RAM consumption is at 29.81MB (already too high, since at this point I'm loading an image from xaml that's 54KB). When showing the 168KB file, it goes to 60-80MB!

Now I go to the next page by calling:

```
        var modalPage = new SomeContentPage();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(modalPage);
```

Then, I load a list of objects from a json file with these lines:

```
  Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Constants.APP_NAMESPACE + ".someJson.json");
            StreamReader re = new StreamReader(stream);
            string content = re.ReadToEnd();
            this._animals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(content);
            re.Dispose(); //adding this reduced the consumption by 20MB. Or maybe I'm so desperate at this point that I thought there was an improvement.
            stream.Dispose();
```

Deserialized using:

```
this._someList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObjects>>(someJsonSource)
```

Based on the "current position of the page." I assign it to the current object (the imgBackground is an Image, of course):

```
imgBackground.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(Constants.APP_NAMESPACE + ".Resources." + someObject.ImageFileName);
```

The list of someObject only contains 10 items, with four string fields.

Can anyone help with this? Is this a known issue of some sort?